# About the classification of surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

You say that a orientable surface (without border) is the sphere $S^2$ or connected sum of tori $T \# T \# \dots \# T$.

In case it is not orientable, is connected sum of projective planes $\mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2 \# \dots \# \mathbb{R}P^2$.

So, what happens with the surface $T \# \mathbb{R}P^2$?

I know it is not orientable. But it is not expressed as unique connected sum of projective planes.

Please, help me.

Comment: $T\#\mathbb{R}P^2$ is the same as $\mathbb{R}P^2\#\mathbb{R}P^2\#\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: So $T$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2$? It seems that definetively any surface is a sphere or connected sum of projective planes, no?

Comment: No, $T$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2\#\mathbb{R}P^2$. Two projective planes together actually make a Klein bottle, and that is certainly not homeomorphic to a torus! My statement is equivalent to saying there is no difference between attaching a torus to a projective plane, and attaching a klein bottle to a projective plane.

Comment: Thanks! So, you can´t get as finally expression of a surface something as $T \# \mathbb{R}P^2 \# T \# T \# \dots \# \mathbb{R}P^2$? Finally, it would be only connected sum of tori or projective planes, uniquely, yeah?

Comment: Yes, ultimately any expression as a sum of both tori and projective planes can be expressed as a sum purely of projective planes. If you know a little commutative algebra, this is equivalent to saying that the set of all compact surfaces is a monoid (like a group but no inverses) with generators $T$ and $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and the relation $\mathbb{R}P^2\#\mathbb{R}P^2\#\mathbb{R}P^2=\mathbb{R}P^2\#T$.